# How to include a library in another site collection?

Tags: list, document-library, site-collection

In SharePoint 2010, I have a document library and a list in one site collection that I want to include in a page on another site collection. The same users have access to both site collections, and I am a site owner in both.

How can I include those, either with full permissions or read-only?

Comment: check this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0SfpgoEUlIw

Comment: http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2009/01/22/a-simple-method-to-display-a-list-in-another-site/

Answer (score 1):

You could use a page viewer web part to view content from other websites (including a different SharePoint site collection).

You'll likely need to use the isDlg=1 parameter on the query string for the page viewer source, and you might even need to create a custom view on the original list that checks the querystring in order to hide ribbon elements or anything else you don't want to show up in your pageviewer with some css.

Note this will only work to provide a view of the external list, you won't be able to use it in any lookup columns or in any other way like it was native to the site collection.